# XNA FBX model drawing problems, it's either my code, the way I export models or the way content is exported

Tags: math, graphics, model, xna

So basically when I try to draw more a mesh inside an FBX file its orientation is always removed and it's scaled down. I'm not sure if the issue is caused by code or the way I'm exporting the FBX files. I have been trying to narrow down the cause and I am fairly sure it's not caused by the way I export the FBX (but I could be wrong), so it's either the XNA content pipeline or my drawing code

Here are some pics I took to show my problem, where the gray background is in 3Ds Max as I see it and red background is in XNA:

THis is as it appears in 3D StudioMax: https://i.stack.imgur.com/e0oW4.png

This is how it appears in XNA: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1vOcx.png

Both are being viewed from the same angle and direction but varying distances.

Now what is really odd is if I create another mesh in max, say a box, and export that (along with the original model), it works fine: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SIDg9.png

So long as there is more than one mesh in the fbx model it draws properly (though I'm still suspicious if it's drawing with proper scaling applied, i.e. if in Max it is 1 unit long in XNA it becomes something like 1.27 units long), if there is less its orientation which I applied to it in 3D studio max is removed when I draw it.

This is how I draw the model:

```
model.CopyAbsoluteBoneTransformsTo(boneTransforms);
foreach (ModelMesh mesh in model.Meshes)
{
foreach (BasicEffect effect in mesh.Effects)
{
effect.World = boneTransforms[mesh.ParentBone.Index];
Vector3 cameraPosition = Camera.Get.Position;// new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
//cameraPosition.X = -Camera.Get.PosX;
//cameraPosition.Y = Camera.Get.PosY;
effect.View = Camera.Get.View;// Matrix.CreateLookAt(cameraPosition, cameraPosition + Camera.Get.LookDir, Camera.Get.Up);

effect.Projection = Matrix.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView(MathHelper.PiOver4,
BaseGame.Get.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.AspectRatio,
0.01f, 1000000); //Matrix.CreateOrthographic(800 / 1, 480 / 1, 0, 1000000);

//effect.TextureEnabled = true;
effect.LightingEnabled = true;
effect.PreferPerPixelLighting = true;
//effect.SpecularColor = new Vector3(1, 0, 0);
}

mesh.Draw();
}
```

Obviously mesh.draw() is called twice when there is more than one mesh in the fbx file..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally if you are having a problem with the position or scale of the mesh while rendering, then it's likely to be related to the matrices.  Not necessarily the exporting, but rather how you use them in the code.

I use blender3d for modelling, but I know that Blender3d actually defines different spaces when you are creating the meshes within the editor.  For example, if you create a mesh while in 'object' mode, the position/rotation/scale of the object in the scene will not be exported (because that object will be the root of a new tree, centered around 0,0,0).  So I would check for a similar situation in 3DMax - make sure you are transforming the vertices in Max relative to 0,0,0, or else you may lose the 'initial' translation and when you render in XNA, all the objects will be rendered around your 0,0,0 (i.e. appear mixed together).

Failing that, and I can't remember exactly off the top of my head, but I think you may need to multiply the current mesh's absolute matrix transform with that of the parent's world matrix transform.  Although it's been a while so I'm not too sure.